# Python class call

Tags: python, oop

I am brand new writing and calling classes in Python. I have a class I created and I am trying too call it

```
class writePDF(object):
    def __init__(self,pdfn,hname,hnfont,PDFdic,rowfont,line):
        self.pdfn = pdfn
        self.hname = hname
        self.hnfont = hnfont
        self.PDFdic = PDFdic
        self.rowfont = rowfont
        self.line = line
    def header(self):
        c = canvas.Canvas(self.pdfn, pagesize=landscape(legal))
        c.setFontSize(self.hnfont),c.drawCentredString(500, 585, self.hname)
        for k,v in self.PDFdic.items():
            c.setFontSize(self.rowfont)
            c.drawString(v[0],v[1],k)
            c.line(self.line)
    def rows(self,layer,fields,loc,fs,locbreak,locreset):
        loc = loc
        counter = 0
        for row in arcpy.da.searchCursor(layer,fields):
            c.setFontSize(fs)
            c.drawString(5, loc, null(row[0]))
            c.drawString(25, loc, null(row[1]))
            c.drawString(180, loc, null(row[2]))
            c.drawString(320, loc, null(row[3]))
            c.drawString(440, loc, null(row[4]))
            c.drawString(500, loc, null(row[5]))
            c.drawString(550, loc, null(row[6]))
            c.drawString(590, loc, null(row[7]))
            c.drawString(650, loc, null(row[8]))
            c.drawString(700, loc, null(row[9]))
            c.drawString(760, loc, null(row[10]))
            c.drawString(830, loc, null(row[11]))
            c.drawString(890, loc, null(row[12]))
            c.drawString(940, loc, null(row[13]))
            loc = loc-13
            if loc <= locbreak:
                c.showPage()
                self.header()
                loc = locreset
            c.save()
```

when I call it:

```
PDFheader = writePDF(pdffn,hname,20,PDFdicE,10,line)
PDFrow = writePDF.rows(sorte,fields,530,10,530)
```

it gives me this error

```
PDFrow = writePDF.rows(sorte,fields,530,10,530)
TypeError: unbound method rows() must be called with writePDF instance as first argument (got Result instance instead)
```

what is the correct syntax to call a class to create an object? should the two functions be there own classes?

Comment: Just a quick suggestion, you should follow python convention and name your classes starting with an uppercase `WritePDF` and your instances starting with a lower case and using underscores between words `pdf_row`. This will help avoid name collisions.

Comment: The `rows` function probably shouldn't be in the class, since it never uses `self`. It's completely standalone.

Comment: so it should either be its own class or just standalone function?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich the reason I included in the class is because I call on the writeHeader method in the rows method

Comment: A class name should also be a noun (`PDFWriter`), not a verb. Verbs are for method names.

Comment: @ziggy: if writeHeader is a method (it's not in the code you show), then you should call it with `self.writeHeader()`. If you just call `writeHeader()` then it looks for a function outside the class with that name.

Comment: Also your rows method uses a variable called `c` that doesn't exist in it, that's probably an error.

Comment: You don't have a `writeHeader` method. It should probably be `self.header(...)`, although `write_header` would be a more conventional name.

Comment: thanks for the comments, i clearly need some work on my understanding of classes. @RemcoGerlich variable c is from Reportlab, that wont throw an error

Comment: @ziggy: well it's confusing because in the `header` method you create a local variable named `c`, but in the `rows` method it's a global variable created elsewhere?

Comment: ahh haa gotcha, il make that a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling it incorrectly

```
PDFheader = writePDF(pdffn,hname,20,PDFdicE,10,line)
PDFrow = PDFheader.rows(sorte,fields,530,10,530)
```

Once you have instantiated the class, you need to then call the method with the created class *PDFheader".

Comment: Another note, you should probably look into PEP8 Python conventions so you're code is a little "prettier"